# PowerBI Bi-Directional Filter DirectQuery

Tags: filter, ssas, powerbi, dax, tabular

I have read here that PowerBI now supports bi-directional filter using power query.

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-desktop-bidirectional-filtering/

I installed the new powerbi version, but once I go on options as described, this option does not seem available for me on the preview features.

I am building a model connected to Analysis Services with multiple Fact Tables,  and this would be very much in handy, since the report uses slicers to filter the report.

If somehow this it not possible and since these relationships are merely to filter the report, I guess I am only left with trying to merge these tables into one right?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Please edit your title to ask a question rather than list tags. It really helps folks scanning the question list to determine whether they can help you.

Comment: It sounds like you may be talking about using "Live Connection" (i.e. connecting to an SSAS model) rather than "Direct Query" (i.e. connecting to a database). https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/Difference-between-live-connection-and-direct-query-mode/td-p/34114

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was looking for

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/Difference-between-live-connection-and-direct-query-mode/td-p/34114